# Help with table multicolumn

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm going crazy in trying to draw the following table in LaTeX:

[image]

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance

Here's what I've done:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c}

   A & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}\\ E & F \\ C\\
   D & G\\


\end{tabular}
```

Thank you all, guys, but I have to draw a table just using the following packages: array, multirow, tabularx, and the supertabular.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That is not multirow, but multicolumn. Can you show us what you have tried so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer: here's what I've done: \begin{tabular}{c c c}
   
   A & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B}\\ E & F \\ C\\
   D & G\\

   
\end{tabular}

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking to generate?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
   \hline
   A & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{B} &  C\\
   \hline
   D & E & F & G\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
A & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{B} & C \\ \hline
D & E & F & G \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably don't want the `|` vertical bar to the *left* of "`l`" in `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{B}`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline}

\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

{\setlength\fboxsep{-0.6pt}\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\fcolorbox{RoyalBlue4}{white}{\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{\rule[-8.5mm]{0pt}{20mm}}m{2.5cm}}}
  A & \multicolumn{2}{>{\rule[-8.5mm]{0pt}{20mm}}l|}{B} & C\\
  \hline
  D & E & F & G
  \end{tabular}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution using only `array`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\setlength\fboxsep{-0.6pt}\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.6pt}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|>{\rule[-8.5mm]{0pt}{20mm}}m{2.5cm}}}
  A & \multicolumn{2}{>{\rule[-8.5mm]{0pt}{20mm}}l|}{B} & C\\
  \hline
  D & E & F & G
  \end{tabular}}}

\end{document} %
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all, guys, but I have to draw a table just using the following packages: array, multirow, tabularx, and the supertabular.

Comment: I've made a simpler version. Please see my updated answer.